# WMP Issue with full screen

Tags: c#, fullscreen, bounds, wmp

I'm working on a C# application that needs to use Window Media Player in a control in a windows form, and (at the same time) fullscreen on primary monitor and secondary monitor.

I want a Windows Forms application on one screen with a user-interface to control bounds primary screen to secondary screen or something like that, and I'd like to show full screen without buffering or black out when I bound screen primary monitor to secondary monitor. The thing is that video is always black out on secondary screen when I bound primary monitor to secondary monitor but still it is playing(I hear the sounds).

Is this buffering issue?

```
public bool IsFullScreen()
        {
            if (wmp_ui_player.fullScreen.Equals(true))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
public void set_formLocation(Form form, Screen screen)
        {
            Rectangle bounds = screen.Bounds;
            form.SetBounds(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using Video Overlay. What OS and graphics card are you using?

Comment: Well, I'm using Windows 7 Professional K; the primary monitor is using Intel(R) G41 Express Chipset(Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1) and the secondary is using same thing. Hope you understand.